# Windows 10 cpu usage not above 27%

Tags: windows-10, cpu, power-supply, cpu-usage

For a while now I noticed my laptop has been slowing down. This is a pretty  powerful machine. After a short investigation I see that my cpu usage never ever exceeds 27%. Looks like a power settings issue to me.

I checked the power setting `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings\Processor power management\maximumum power state` and it was already set to 100%, so it doesn't seem that that is the problem.

After that I checked the cpu temp with CoreTemp and it was around 44 Celsius. Nothing special.

After that I checked the usage of all the different cores in the task manager  and all of them seemed to work (each individual core showing slightly different utility, all below 27% at all times).

EDIT

This is restarting MS teams, outlook, spotify, intellij and paint. Should be enough only for a millisecond to peak a bit wouldn't you think?

[image]

Comment: Running a benchmark should push the CPU to 100%. What model is your laptop and what else did you try so far? Is there any external application that could throttle the CPU?

Comment: See above edit for a what it looks like

Comment: Sanity check - Your machine isn't in a power saving mode is it? I see it it plugged in, but I think it is still possible to set it to power saving mode even while plugged in.

Comment: Not that I know of. But as stated in the question I checked the power save mode. Seemed all right. But since I'm not a power-save expert I hope to have overlooked a secret hidden windows option that resolves all of this

Answer (score 0):

Btw, i have the same problem sometimes. This has helped me so far every time: 
Remove the charging cable, wait a few seconds, (CPU should go back to normal performance) plug the cable back in and CPU should stay at normal performance.